# Perfomance depending on index type

Tags: performance, graphics, vulkan

I was playing around with "drawing" millions of triangles and found something interesting: switching type of indices from `VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32` to `VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16` increased amount of triangles being drawn per second by 1.5 times! I want to know, how is the difference in speed so large?

I use indirect indexed instanced (so much i) drawing: 25 vertices, 138 indices(46 triangles), 2^21~=2M instances(I am too lazy to seek where to disable vSync), 1 draw per frame. 96'468'992 triangles per frame total. To get the clearest results I look away from the triangles (discarding rasterisation has pretty much same performance)

I have very simple vertex shader:

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform A
{
    mat4 cam;
};

layout(location = 0)in vec3 inPosition;//
layout(location = 1)in vec4 inColor;   //Color and position are de-interleaved
layout(location = 2)in vec3 inGlob;    //
layout(location = 3)in vec4 inQuat;    //data per instance, interleaved

layout(location = 0)out vec4 fragColor;

vec3 vecXquat(const vec3 v, const vec4 q)
{// function rotating vector by quaternion
    return v + 2.0f *
           cross(q.xyz,
           cross(q.xyz, v)
                + q.w * v);
}

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(vecXquat(inPosition, inQuat)+inGlob, 1.0f)*cam;
    fragColor = inColor;
}
```

and pass-through fragment shader.

Primitives - `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST`

The results:

~1950MTris/s with 32bit indices

~2850MTris/s with 16bit indices

GPU - GTX1050Ti

Comment: Btw, switching from triangle lists to triangle strips bumps the perfomance in a similiar way - for 32bit indices, and slightly decreases for 16bit. Though my model is quite small, with bigger model there could be big differences. And as I learnt recently, ~3000MTris/s is a hardware limit for my GPU...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your shaders are so simple, your rendering performance will likely be dominated by factors that would otherwise be more trivial, like vertex data transfer rate.

138 indices have to be read by the GPU for each instance. With 2 million instances, that's 1.02GB of just index data that has to be read by the GPU with 32-bit indices. Of course, for 16-bit indices, the transfer rate is halved. And with half as much data, there's a better chance that the index data all manages to fit entirely in the vertex pulling cache.